# Why can't `std::experimental::make_array` use `std::reference_wrapper`?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template <class D, class...> 
struct return_type_helper 
{ 
  using type = D; 
};

template <class... Types>
struct return_type_helper<void, Types...> : std::common_type<Types...> 
{
  static_assert(
    // why can't I use reference wrappers?
    std::conjunction_v<not_ref_wrapper<Types>...>,
    "Types cannot contain reference_wrappers when D is void"
  );
};

template <class D = void, class... Types>
constexpr std::array<typename return_type_helper<D, Types...>::type, sizeof...(Types)> make_array(Types&&... t) 
{
  return {std::forward<Types>(t)...};
}

void foo()
{
  int x = 7355608;
  auto arr = make_array(std::ref(x)); // does not compile
}
```

Why does `std::experimental::make_array()` have a `static_assert()` that disallows use of `std::reference_wrapper` when the type of the array is automatically deduced? Creating an array of reference wrappers is otherwise perfectly legal, that is the compiler has no problem with

```
auto arr2 = std::array<decltype(std::ref(x)),1>{std::ref(x)};
```

Comment: raw arrays of references are not allowed, so maybe they are extending that semantic to this as well?

Comment: I guess the idea is if you want an array of reference wrappers you should ask for that, and if you want an array of references you can't have one.

Comment: Since they added a deduction guide for `std::array` in C++20 and ditched the `make_array` idea it's perhaps not worth digging to deep into this?

Comment: Removing the static assert and inspecting the type of `arr` (via LSP) however shows that it constructs an array of `std::reference_wrapper`s which is legal: `struct std::array<std::reference_wrapper<int>, 1>`

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have to work with a C++11 baseline so cannot use CTAD :(

Comment: You can make your own version of this and replace `std::array<typename return_type_helper<D, Types...>::type, sizeof...(Types)>` with `std::array<typename std::common_type<Types...>::type, sizeof...(Types)>`

Comment: @NathanOliver yes that's essentially what I've done -- removing the `static_assert()` -- but was wary of removing the check since I couldn't see an obvious reason for why it was in there...

Comment: Based on the code you’ve posted, you *can* use `make_array` with `std::reference_wrapper<T>` — you just need to explicitly specify its type when calling `make_array`. The fact that the code distinguishes explicitly specified template types from inferred ones suggests to me that this is done so that users avoid surprises. Users could reasonably expect usage of `std::ref` to infer a reference type for the elements, because that is precisely how `std::ref` is used in other contexts. The API design is defensive.

Comment: > so that users avoid surprises.

Sorry for being pedantic but could you elaborate on this? Surprise as in somehow accidentally constructing reference wrappers? Or accidentally extracting reference wrappers from the array vs what is contained in the reference wrappers via iteration?

Comment: @JacobFaib Well, like I said: the user might reasonably expect that this would construct an array of *references*, not an array of `reference_wrapper`s. From the API it seems clear that the intent is to avoid this ambiguity, and if the user actually wants an array of `reference_wrapper`s they explicitly need to opt in to that by calling `make_array<std::reference_wrapper<T>>()`.

Comment: > this would construct an array of references. Hmmmm I don't follow. Containers of references are illegal no? Or are you saying that users may think that by using `std::ref()` they can somehow get an array of references to the elements via implicit conversion `std::reference_wrapper::operator T&()`?

Comment: @JacobFaib When replying to a comment please @-mention the person you’re replying to so they get notified. — Arrays of references are indeed illegal, and can’t be constructed. However, the user of `make_array` might be careless, and forgot this. [Good APIs are designed to be hard to use incorrectly by accident](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/97-things-every/9780596809515/ch55.html); that’s why `make_array` intentionally makes it harder to make this mistake.

Comment: > However, the user of make_array might be careless, and forgot this. @KonradRudolph right but this does not seem like a case where it is possible to accidentally footgun, so why guard against something that doesn't compile anyways? Can you show a case where one would be able to accidentally construct an array of references? I have tried `std::array<int&,1> x = {some_int}`, `auto x = std::array<int&,1>{some_int}`, `auto x = make_array<int&>(some_int);` and none of them compile.

Comment: @JacobFaib But it does compile (once you remove the specialisation with the `static_assert`). It just doesn’t construct the expected type. And since `reference_wrapper` and references (intentionally) behave quite similarly but not identically, the erroneous code might lead to subtly wrong behaviour somewhere else.

Comment: > But it does compile (once you remove the specialization with the static_assert). @KonradRudolph sorry missed the mention. Can you be specific? None of the instances in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72319915/why-cant-stdexperimentalmake-array-use-stdreference-wrapper#comment127814320_72319915) [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/Ef3EoPvvj). > It just doesn’t construct the expected type. I'm not sure I follow on what you mean. `std::ref()` always constructs a `std::reference_wrapper` does it not? So expected type would be a `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @JacobFaib It doesn’t compile because of the `static_assert`. Without that, [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/fx58MK7Ko) — but constructs a potentially unexpected type. That’s my whole point (and, I suspect, the reason the authors included the `static_assert`). In fact, I just checked the proposal, and it says exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the proposal [N3824](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3824.htm) confirms my initial suspicion.

Namely, the `static_assert` check was added to explicitly disallow type deduction of a `std::array<std::reference_wrapper<T>, N>` from `make_array`, because the proposal’s author has deemed this usage error-prone.<sup>1</sup>

That is, with the following code:

```
auto x = 42;
auto a = make_array(std::ref(x));
```

users could reasonably expect the type of `a` to be `std::array<int&, 1>`, because `std::ref` behaves similarly in other contexts.

In reality `std::array<int&, 1>` does not name a valid type and *cannot* be constructed, so the danger of this confusion is minimal. Still, the author found it worth erring on the side of caution here, and making the API maximally defensive.

Consequently, if the user wants to create an array of reference wrappers, they need to explicitly request that type:

```
auto a = make_array<std::reference_wrapper<int>>(std::ref(x));
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Here’s the proposal’s wording:

> Ban `reference_wrapper` in the `make_tuple`-like interface. `make_tuple` and `make_pair` have special handling of `reference_wrapper`, then user might expect that the expression
>
> ```
> make_array(ref(a), ref(b))
> ```
>
> also results in a tuple-like object storing `T&`.

Comment: > make_tuple and make_pair have special handling of reference_wrapper, then user might expect that the expression... also results in a tuple-like object storing T&. The connection to `std::make_tuple()` and `std::make_pair()` was the missing link. Now it makes sense why the author wanted explicit opt-in, thanks for clearing this up!